# How to Place Items From A Dictionary in VM To An Ordered List

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm looking for a way to place items from a dictionary into the same row in a business-logic proper order

e.g. an item that has a system identifier typeone, then typetwo for every row.

The dictionary has one key to many values, and I want the values to be listed in the same order for every instance of every key. I'm guaranteed that at least one of the values exist but not both.

For example, one row:

```
            <tr>
                <td>@vendorItemKeys.Key.Vendor</td>
                <td>@vendorItemKeys.Key.ItemCode</td>
                @foreach (var vendorItemDetail in Model.UpcItems[topLevelKey]
                {
                    @if (vendorItemDetail.SystemIdentifier == SystemIdentifier.typeOne)
                     {
                         <td>@vendorItemDetail.CaseUpc</td>
                         <td>@vendorItemDetail.Description</td>
                         <td>@vendorItemDetail.CasePack</td>
                         <td>@vendorItemDetail.Size</td>
                         <td>@vendorItemDetail.SystemIdentifier</td>
                     }
                    else if (vendorItemDetail.SystemIdentifier == SystemIdentifier.typeTwo)
                    {
                        <td>@vendorItemDetail.CaseUpc</td>
                        <td>@vendorItemDetail.Description</td>
                        <td>@vendorItemDetail.CasePack</td>
                        <td>@vendorItemDetail.Size</td>
                        <td>@vendorItemDetail.SystemIdentifier</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td> 
                    }
                }
            </tr>
```

However this code doesn't account for the fact that if I grab typeTwo first, the typeOne it would display in reverse.  Any suggestions on how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a `switch` could help (apols is my razor is ropey):

```
            @foreach (var vendorItemDetail in Model.UpcItems[topLevelKey].OrderBy(f => SomeOrderFunction()))
            {
                switch(vendorItemDetail.SystemIdentifier)
                {
                    case SystemIdentifier.typeOne:
                    case SystemIdentifier.typeTwo:
                    @{
                         <td>@vendorItemDetail.CaseUpc</td>
                         <td>@vendorItemDetail.Description</td>
                         <td>@vendorItemDetail.CasePack</td>
                         <td>@vendorItemDetail.Size</td>
                         <td>@vendorItemDetail.SystemIdentifier</td>
                    }
                        break;
                    case default:
                    @{
                         <td></td>
                         <td></td>
                         <td></td>
                         <td></td>
                         <td></td>
                    }
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: The .OrderBy function was the key to solving this one.  Thanks!